# Does proving the injectivity of an inverse function imply that the original function must be surjective?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove a bijection and I was able to prove that the function was injective. If i solve for the inverse, can i prove it's injectivity and thus assume surjectivity?

f(a)=2a+1 is injective,
a=(f(a)-1)/2 is injective,
would f(a) be proven surjective since every f(a) has one unique output a?

a is in the set of natural numbers and f(a) goes to the set of all postive odd integers.

Comment: "*If I solve for the inverse*" To be clear... an inverse relation or an inverse function?  Are you aware of the difference?  How do you find an inverse function when $f$ is *not* surjective?  For an example... suppose we have $f~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ given by $f(a)=2a+1$.  Yes, that *is* injective.  You talk about "the inverse" and call it $f^{-1}(b)=\frac{b-1}{2}$ but why should this exist in the first place?  Note that for $b$ odd it will result in an integer but for $b$ even it will be a non-integer and thus invalid input.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are assuming the function is invertible before proving that it is invertible... and the act of assuming the function is invertible of course is equivalent to assuming that the function is both injective and surjective, making this all circular logic.  As for the inverse *relation* being injective, that alone does not imply the function is surjective, merely that the function where we restrict its codomain to the *range* of the function would be a bijection which is not the same thing as proving the function is a bijection with respect to its full codomain.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ has an inverse if and only if the function is both injective and surjective. In the case that $f$ has an inverse, its inverse $f^{-1}$ also has an inverse, namely

$$(f^{-1})^{-1}=f.$$

Therefore $f^{-1}$ is automatically injective and surjective when it exists.